# How do I add a 'x' button to the top right to close out of the modal?

Tags: modal-dialog, exit

```html
<div class="ReactModal__Overlay ReactModal__Overlay--after-open Modal__Overlay Modal__Overlay--popup" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s !important; top: 96px !important;"><div class="ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open Modal  Modal--large  Modal--popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-label="Modal"><div class="Modal__Content" style="opacity: 1; transform: none;"><div><div class="Modal__InnerScrollbar"><div class="ChargeAfterLauncher__WhereDoYouShopModal"><div class="ChargeAfterLauncher__WhereDoYouShopModalHeading"><p><span data-contrast="auto" xml:lang="EN-US" lang="EN-US" class="TextRun SCXW211149180 BCX9"><span class="NormalTextRun SCXW211149180 BCX9">To provide you with a personalized experience, please let us know where you intend to shop with us:</span></span>
  <span class="EOP SCXW211149180 BCX9" data-ccp-props="{&quot;201341983&quot;:0,&quot;335559739&quot;:160,&quot;335559740&quot;:259}">&nbsp;</span></p></div><div class="ChargeAfterLauncher__WhereDoYouShopModalSubheading">Where do you expect to shop?</div><div class="FormLayout"><form class="ChargeAfterLauncher__WhereDoYouShopModalForm"><div class="FormLayout__Row  FormLayout__Row--mobile-flex"><div class="FormLayout__Item"><div class="FormField FormField--filled FormField--radio-group FormField--no-float"><fieldset><div class="ChargeAfterLauncher__WhereDoYouShopRadioGroup"><div class="FormField FormField--filled FormField--radio FormField--no-float"><label class="FormField__Label" for="online"><span class="FormField__RadioWrapper u-position-relative"><input class="FormField__Radio u-absolute-fill" type="radio" id="online" value="online-only" checked=""><span class="FormField__RadioMark"></span></span><span class="FormField__FloatingLabel">Online</span></label></div><div class="FormField FormField--filled FormField--radio FormField--no-float"><label class="FormField__Label" for="in-store"><span class="FormField__RadioWrapper u-position-relative"><input class="FormField__Radio u-absolute-fill" type="radio" id="in-store" value="in-store"><span class="FormField__RadioMark"></span></span><span class="FormField__FloatingLabel">In Store</span></label></div></div></fieldset></div></div></div><div class="FormLayout__Row"><div class="FormLayout__Item"><button class="Button Button--primary" type="button" title="Continue"><span class="Button__Text" aria-hidden="false">Continue</span></button></div></div></form></div></div></div>

</div></div></div></div>
```

I am looking to add a 'x' to the top right of a popup modal so user can exit out of the modal.

Current code:
`

To provide you with a personalized experience, please let us know where you intend to shop with us:

Where do you expect to shop?OnlineIn StoreContinue

`

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuRUZ.png)